# Nullaware operator doesn't seem to work inside a Text widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable

I have simple code as follows:

```
  class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String myString = 'abc';
  static double myDouble;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    try {
      myDouble = double.parse(myString) + 5;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          '$myDouble' ?? 'Ok',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Since `myDouble` is going to return null, I expect the `Text` widget to take in `'Ok'` and rendre the same. However, I still see null shown on the screen.

[image]

Any help as to why this is not working please. Thank you.

Additionally, I do not understand why I cannot use `try catch` block before build method as it gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: This question is regarding Dart before the [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety). With null-safety on, this scenario would not happen.

In your case, even though `myDouble` is null, when you do

```
'$variable'
```

You are creating a *new* string which isn`t null (which is denoted by the `"` or `'` signs).

So the 'ok' after the null-aware operator would never be called anyway.
Also, using `${var}` inside a string is called [String Interpolation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings), which as the documentation states:

> To get the string corresponding to an object, Dart calls the object’s toString() method.

And, the `toString()` method on a null object returns simply `null`, which results in your text displaying null.

There are many ways for the desired result, you could do, as an example:

```
(myDouble == null) ?  'ok' : '$myDouble' ,
```

Just as a reminder, [Dart now supports null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety), which you should be using in new codes (and migrating old ones). With null safety, you probably would have notice this error before.

Comment: @MartinBackasch You are correct! Thank you for your note :) It was a mistake.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually I am using latest dart sdk version that supports null safety. But that apart I understood that '$' returns null string and .toString also returns null string.

Answer (score 1):

`Text('$myDouble')` converts the null to string null

```
'$myDouble' is now 'null'(string)
```

to manage null String variables you can do this either of the ways

```
Text(myDouble == null ? 'Ok' : myDouble.toString);
```